# Error on getting google maps info

Tags: python, html, google-maps

I'm having a trouble when accessing google api.

I use python and python modlue Googlemaps.

I was going to get the routing information with the code below.

```
directions_result = gmaps.directions(IN,OUT,mode="driving",
departure_time="2018-04-05 09:00:00",
traffic_model='pessimistic',alternatives=False,language="ja")
```

http error 400 hits me when I try to make it work.

It works actually without "depature_time"...so something might be wrong with it, FYI.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to send key as well?

Comment: @Itay4 thank you for your comment! ofcourse ive already been through the process

Comment: You mean http and not html, right?

Comment: From the documentation: `The departure_time must be set to the current time or some time in the future. It cannot be in the past.` So, assuming `04` is the month, I think that's the issue.

Comment: @MegaIng yeah true its http error...sorry. any tip for that?

Comment: @Itay4 thanks again! I tried with `departure_time="2018-05-05 09:00:00"` but the same error comes up...

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that `departure_time` expects to get `Time` object?

Comment: @Itay4 i didnt know that actually...i tried to figure it out but i don't know yet how to set it up...

Answer (score 0):

`departure_time` accepts `Time` object, so your code should look as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime
date_format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
departure_time = datetime.strptime('2018-05-05 09:00:00', date_format)
directions_result = gmaps.directions(IN,OUT,mode="driving",
                                     departure_time=departure_time,
                                     traffic_model='pessimistic',
                                     alternatives=False,
                                     language="ja")
```